# Print a specific column of a csv file using batch

Tags: batch-file

lets assume the data in the file (data.csv) as,

```
A1, B1, C1, D1, E1
A2, B2, C2, D2, E2
A3, B3, C3, D3, E3
```

This is the script I have written

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= ",%%x in (C:\Users\arunb\data.csv) DO echo %%x
```

if I want to print the data in the fourth column what I have to do?
the code which I have is not giving any outputs.

Comment: To start with, therte asre no columns in a CSV file, there are simply fields separated by a known character, (most commonly, a comma). Why are we assuming that the data in the CSV is like this ```A1, B1, C1, D1, E1```? My assumption would be that the data would read as ```A1,B1,C1,D1,E1```, or ```"A1","B1","C1","D1","E1"```. I do not see any reason why the field data in each record, except for the first, would begin with a single whitespace character. Could you please open your `.csv` file in a plain text editor, and copy the actual format, instead of asking us to make unlikely assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
`...delims=, " %%x...`
```

BUT

Your code worked for me, generating `D1,`, `D2,`, `D3,`.

In all probability, your file has *nix-ish line-endings. `cmd` requires `<CR><LF>`

Your `,` between the `"` and `%%x` is not *wrong* per se, but *unusual*. It's just a separator in this position, same as the conventional <kbd>Space</kbd>

The syntax I have posted will use both <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> as separators and generate `D1`, `D2`, `D3`.